# TextView setShowSoftInputOnFocus equivalent before SDK 21?

Tags: android, textview, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText` and I'd like my app to NEVER show the soft keyboard when I focus on it. I'm using an external keyboard.

I'd like to do this in my activity's `onCreate`:

```
EditText debugPrompt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.debug_prompt);
debugPrompt.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Problem is, I'm using SDK 19, and `setShowSoftInputOnFocus` was added in 21. Is there any equivalent?

My best try so far is:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
EditText debugPrompt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.debug_prompt);
debugPrompt.requestFocus();
```

This does part of the job. The keyboard is hidden after line 4, but shows itself when I tap inside the `EditText`.

Comment: I solved this by upgrading my SDK. An answer would probably still be useful for any developers who can't upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void disableinputRetaincursor(EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```